# Missing subtotal ribbon from Excel 2011 Mac

Tags: excel, macos

I'm trying to find the subtotal button to calculate the subtotal of a column. What I can't seem to find is the ribbon for Subtotal. Everywhere on the internet says that it's in the Data tab but there is no such ribbon there. I tried to add it in by going to 'customize ribbons/toolbar' where it says drag the Subtotal option to the toolbar, but it won't allow that either. Any help?

Comment: Check the "Formulas" tab.

Comment: @jbarker2160 it's in there but my workbook has a box with options that include having a summary below the table, 'at each change in', 'use function', 'add subtotal to' etc. I just get the =SUBTOTAL() function in a cell

Comment: That's because the subtotal function has 9 possible operations(SUM, AVG, MIN, MAX, etc.) and you have to choose the appropriate one and the range.

Comment: [This](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/631934-missing-subtotal-command.html) might help you.